# Why aren't empty ticks working with empty plots?

Tags: pgfplots, axis, ticks

I need to do an empty plot for my students to fill. Surprisingly the options `xtick=\empty`  and `ytick=\empty` do not work when the plot is empty:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[width=10cm, height=4cm, scale only axis,
  axis lines=center,
  xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
  xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$f$]
%   \addplot {x+1};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

I have been able to achieve my ends with the option `ticks=none` as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44966/46718), but this is not totally satisfactory since  this workaround does not allow to cancel ticks on a single axis if needed. Besides I was not able to find this option in the Pgfplots documentation.

Why the `\empty` command does not work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the range of coordinates calculates according to its content. When it's missing I believe, pgfplots just draws default axis, ignoring most options (notice that `axis lines=center` doesn't work either).

You have three options:

1. Disable ticks with `ticks=none` as you described. If you want to eliminate only x ticks or y ticks, you can set `xmajorticks=false` or `xmajorticks=false` similarly

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

   \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=10cm, height=4cm, scale only axis,
     axis lines=center,
     xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$f$,
     xmajorticks=false
     ]
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```
2. Put something invisible via `\addplot` so the data of axis isn't blank

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

   \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=10cm, height=4cm, scale only axis,
     axis lines=center,
     xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
     xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$f$,
     ]
      \addplot[draw=none]{0};
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```
3. And the most correct was is to specify all `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, `ymax` so the axis doesn't rely on content anymore, but the values you set, thus `\empty` works.
   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

   \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=10cm, height=4cm, scale only axis,
     axis lines=center,
     xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
     xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$f$,
     xmin=-1, xmax=5,
     ymin=-3, ymax=2
     ]
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```